# Is Mustache bar for daily ride advisable?

Tags: fixed-gear, drop-bar

I'm using an NJS approved frame for my fixed gear bike. Is it okay for me to use my new Mustache drop bar on my daily ride going to work and back home. a total of 25km per day.

Comment: What is NJS? Not everyone here knows that acronym.

Comment: NJS only means that it's been approved by the Nihon Jitensha Shinkokai or the japanese keirin association. Keirin is a form of motor-paced cycle racing in which track cyclists sprint for victory following a speed-controlled start behind a motorized or non-motorized pacer.

Comment: Personally, anything over 15 minutes becomes uncomfortable with mustache bars.

Comment: Can you please add a photo of your new bars, so we know what you're dealing with.  I mustache in comments for clarification 8-|)

Answer (score 1):

As long as the diameter of the clamp surface is the same as your stem clamp, you can run whatever you want! As far as comfort, that one is up to you. Mustache bars don’t provide the best leverage for cornering or stopping on a fixie.